# Error while trying to build template based code

Tags: c++, templates, function, linked-list

I was trying to write some code, using templates, I've been trying for a few hours now, but still cannot solve this error:

`14 C:\Users\urielbertoche\Desktop\main.cpp request for member 'defineConstante' in 'planilhaTeste', which is of non-class type 'planilha<double> ()()'`

my main at the moment is like:

```
int main (){
planilha<double> planilhaTeste();
unsigned int contador=0;
double number=0;
for(contador=0; contador<5; contador++)
{
      cout<<"Escreva a constante para a celula "<<contador<<endl;
      cin>>number;
      planilhaTeste.defineConstante(contador, number); // this is line 14 by the way
      planilhaTeste->primeiro=planilhaTeste->primeiro->prox;
      cout<<planilhaTeste.termoConstante;
}
return 0;
```

}

all the includes have been made, my header is like:

```
template <class Type>
class planilha{
    protected:
        struct celula{
            double termoConstante;
            Type resultadoFinal;
            lista termos;
            int numCelula;
            celula *prox;
            celula():prox(NULL){};
            celula(double novoTermo, int numCel, celula *proxElo=NULL):termoConstante(novoTermo),
                    resultadoFinal(novoTermo), numCelula(numCel), prox(proxElo), termos(){};
        };
        celula *primeiro;

    public:
        planilha();
        planilha(const planilha<Type>& origem);
        ~planilha(void);
        planilha<Type> operator=(const planilha<Type>& origem);
        void defineConstante(int numCel, const Type& valor);
        bool insere_termo(unsigned int numCel, unsigned int refCel, double fator);
        void apagar(unsigned int num_cel);
};
```

and the function code is:

```
template <class Type>
void planilha<Type>::defineConstante(int numCel, const Type& valor){
    celula * finder = primeiro;
    while(finder!=NULL){
        if(this->numCelula==numCel){
            this->termoConstante = valor;
            return;
        }
        finder=finder->prox;
    }
}
```

I really can't figure why this error is happening. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
planilha<double> planilhaTeste();
```

This line declares a function planilhaTeste returning planilha<double> not a variable of type planilha<double>. As long as you need a default ctor here just remove empty parenthises from the declaration:

```
planilha<double> planilhaTeste;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `main()` function , change line `planilha<double> planilhaTeste();`
 to `planilha<double> planilhaTeste;`

there are some other errors also like : `lista termos; //lista is not even a typedef`

`planilhaTeste->primeiro=planilhaTeste->primeiro->prox;`
planilhaTeste is not pointer, also primeiro is protected which you're trying to access outside scope of `planilha` class